# Python StatsModels - Mixed Model - For numerical factors, num_columns must be an int

Tags: python, statsmodels

I've installed [StatsModels](http://statsmodels.sourceforge.net/devel/install.html) and now im trying to test by running some of their [example](https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels/blob/master/examples/notebooks/mixed_lm_example.ipynb) code

```
import numpy as np
import statsmodels.api as sm
import statsmodels.formula.api as smf
```

^ this all works with no errors

```
data = sm.datasets.get_rdataset('dietox', 'geepack').data
data.head()
```

gives

```
      Weight    Feed      Time  Pig   Evit  Cu  Litter
0   26.50000    NaN         1   4601    1   1   1
1   27.59999    5.200005    2   4601    1   1   1
2   36.50000    17.600000   3   4601    1   1   1
3   40.29999    28.500000   4   4601    1   1   1
4   49.09998    45.200001   5   4601    1   1   1
```

then

```
type(data)
```

returns

```
pandas.core.frame.DataFrame
```

and

```
data.dtypes
```

gives

```
Weight    float64
Feed      float64
Time        int64
Pig         int64
Evit        int64
Cu          int64
Litter      int64
dtype: object
```

But then when I try and make the stats model using

```
md = smf.mixedlm("Weight ~ Time", data, groups=data["Pig"])
```

I get the error

```
ValueError: For numerical factors, num_columns must be an int
```

Does anyone know what is happening here?

Comment: general hint: in python the traceback is very informative, so post the full traceback or at least enough so we see where it breaks. What versions of numpy,.pandas and statsmodels do you use? statsmodels 0.6.1 is not compatible with recent changes in numpy. Recent versions of numpy and pandas require statsmodels 0.8 which should have fixed all version incompatibilities.

Comment: The exception looks like it's coming from a problem in patsy that has been fixed in patsy 0.4.1, AFAIR